# Update an infopath field with return value from webservice submit?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, infopath

Is it possible to update an infopath field with the result of a call to submit to a webservice?  We have an infopath form used to create items in the database.  I would like to add a read only field for the id (primary key) of the item in the infopath form which is filled when the form is submitted to the webservice by the return value.  Is there a way to use the return value as part of a rule with a "Set a field's value" action?  I could not find a way to do this with rules gui.  Is it possible to do this using c# code? Or am I missing something in the GUI?

Comment: Is it your forms Submit() call that returns the value or are you making a different Service call from the code?

Comment: Why are you trying to enter a value in the form AFTER you submit?

Comment: I will not know the id of the new item until after the form has been submitted for the first time.  The user may want to go back later and change the fields to update the db.  This is why I want to save the id as part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer here is that you can't consume the result of a submit query other than success/fail.  The long answer is that you can, without too much extra work, split the query into two parts, first calling the insert portion if the id is null, 0, blank or whatever, then calling the second to update the data with your new id which should now be a part of the form data.